# How can I get Browser.text.include? to be case insensitive?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

It's as simple as that:

How can I get `Browser.text.include?`, or Ruby in general, to be case insensitive for that specified command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to downcase or upcase the text that you're reading:

```
Browser.text.downcase.include?
```

Then, you need to make sure that your desired text is supplied in all lowercase.

Comment: Maybe you downcase both strings?

Comment: @Dave - yes, just depends on how much control you have over the incoming data.  Using downcase on both would be the safest way.

Answer (score 5):

You can use String#match with a regular expression.
e.g.:

```
("CaseSensitive".match /SENSITIVE/i) != nil
```

That will return true if there is a case-insensitive match, false otherwise.
So for the above example, it returns true, as 'SENSITIVE' is found within 'CaseSensitive'.

For your example:

```
(Browser.text.match /yourString/i ) != nil
```